# Will RecyclerView recycle items inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am using two `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`. The setup works great but I am worried about the memory impacts that it can have. I am not sure Whether the RecylerView will recycle components like it does. Are there any other downsides for this?

Here is some code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_coordinator_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycleview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recycleview1"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RecyclerView` does not recycle its items when it is inside a `NestedScrollView`. In fact, when you `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` for a view, it will be expanded fully and scrolling behavior should provide by its parent, which is a `NestedScrollView` in your case. So, if you have an infinite `RecyclerView`, then the memory and performance will be reduced when number of items increases. But as long as number of your items is not so much that can impact the memory and performance, using `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` is not bad or wrong. But it is obvious that it's better not to do that.